# FTX CCXT cancel SL / TP after position closes

Tags: ccxt

I already have the code to send orders to FTX (with TP and SL).

But since TP and SL are not 'attached' to the position and the positions are aggregated it makes a mess with orders.

I have seen people suggest cancelling all orders before opening a new one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69371405/6014804
Which is a nice idea but unusable in my case.

I regularly have several current positions at the same time.

So I can't cancel all pending orders as soon as I open a new position. Because some orders are still active and relevant.

The only option I guess is to fetch closed orders/positions (when a TP / SL is hit) to individually cancel the remaining order to this position (the opposite order, either TP / SL). Right?

Even if it's the right solution, I don't know how to do that.
Has anyone ever experienced that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm citing the solution CCXT team has come up with, on their dedicated GitHub issues platform: https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/15214

- place tp order
- place sl order
- start a polling mechanism to detect when one or another order is
  closed
- after detecting, cancel the remaining

Very rough example:

```
tp_order = await exchange.create_order(...)
sl_order = await exchange.create_order(...)

    while True:
        if tp_status == 'open' and sl_status == 'closed':
            # cancel tp order
            cancel_tp_order = await exchange.cancel_order(tp_order['id'])
            break
        
        if sl_status == 'open' and tp_status == 'closed':
            # cancel sl order
            cancel_sl_order = await exchange.cancel_order(sl_order['id'])
            break
       asyncio.sleep(5) # sleep 5 seconds before trying again
```

Alternatively, you could use WS (they're free now) to detect in real-time which order was filled and immediately close the other.